# Applied Optimization: A box is to be made out of a 6 by 16 piece of cardboard.

Tags: calculus

A box is to be made out of a 6 by 16 piece of cardboard. Squares of equal size will be cut out of each corner, and then the ends and sides will be folded up to form a box with an open top. Find the length L, width W, and height H of the resulting box that maximizes the volume. (Assume that W <= L).
 so far I have this diagram[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?  Have you a picture?

Comment: I have a picture, I'll try to post it :)

Comment: Okay, I edited the main post to include my diagram

Comment: Excellent, so when you fold the sides up what are the dimensions of the resulting box?

Comment: Well I don't know that unless I know x... so... I would see how many x are subtracted from each side...? I'll try!

Comment: You're on the right track: the dimensions of each side will be functions of $x$.

Comment: okay... tell me if this makes sense... Length=16-2x, Width=6-2x, and Height=x?

Comment: Just so!  Now calculate the volume, and maximize it over all possible values of $x$, namely $0\le x\le 3$.  Happy hunting.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is the side of the square, the volume of box, $V=x(16-2x)(6-2x)$, differentiating and equating to zero gives, $V'=(16-2x)(6-2x)-2x(16-x)-2x(6-x)=0$, solve for $x$ to get the maximize value